# Silverlight XAML layout issue

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, silverlight, visual-studio-2008

I am using Silverlight 3.0 + .Net 3.5 + VSTS 2008 + C# to develop a simple video application using the open source slvideoplayer of Silverlight.

http://slvideoplayer.codeplex.com/

For the player, the play control is at the bottom of the rendering video, any ideas how to place play control at the top of video? I have tried hard but can not figure out. Any solutions?

EDIT 1: here is the current XAML code, elements in "controlsContainer" is what I want to put on top of video (i.e. the "mediaPlayer"), here is the effect I want to have, appreciate if you could let me know how to change my code to achieve this goal?

http://i45.tinypic.com/admgq0.png

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Canvas x:Name="PlayIcon" Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.ZIndex="99" Cursor="Hand" MouseLeftButtonUp="PlayIcon_MouseLeftButtonUp">
            <Path Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#77000000" Data="F1 M 15,0L 85,0C 93.2843,0 100,6.71573 100,15L 100,85C 100,93.2843 93.2843,100 85,100L 15,100C 6.71573,100 0,93.2843 0,85L 0,15C 0,6.71573 6.71573,0 15,0 Z "/>
            <Path Width="40.8182" Height="47.1328" Canvas.Left="34.6439" Canvas.Top="27.6003" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="F1 M 75.4621,51.1667L 34.6439,27.6003L 34.6439,74.7331L 75.4621,51.1667 Z "/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas x:Name="LargeSpinnerArea" Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.ZIndex="100" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <VideoPlayer:spinner x:Name="BigBuffer" Width="100" Height="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                    <VideoPlayer:spinner.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="4" ScaleY="4"/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </VideoPlayer:spinner.RenderTransform>
                </VideoPlayer:spinner>
            </StackPanel>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas x:Name="Thumbnail" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" Visibility="Collapsed" Canvas.ZIndex="98">
            <Image x:Name="ThumbnailImage" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
        </Canvas>
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot2" Margin="0" Background="#FF0D0A0A" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Canvas x:Name="VideoCanvas">
                <MediaElement Canvas.ZIndex="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="mediaPlayer" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoPlay="false"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Margin="-1,0,0,0" x:Name="controlsContainer" Height="35" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform Y="0"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Rectangle Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="#97000000" Stroke="#00000000" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
            <VideoPlayer:mediaControl Height="35" Margin="1,0,2,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="mediaControls" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0" Visibility="Visible"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this one. Works fine for me. Last Line StackPanel

```
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <VideoPlayer:spinner x:Name="BigBuffer" Width="100" Height="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                    <VideoPlayer:spinner.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="4" ScaleY="4"/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </VideoPlayer:spinner.RenderTransform>
                </VideoPlayer:spinner>
            </StackPanel>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas x:Name="Thumbnail" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" Visibility="Collapsed" Canvas.ZIndex="98">
            <Image x:Name="ThumbnailImage" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
        </Canvas>
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot2" Margin="0" Background="#FF0D0A0A" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Canvas x:Name="VideoCanvas">
                <MediaElement Canvas.ZIndex="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="mediaPlayer" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoPlay="false"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Margin="-1,0,0,0" x:Name="controlsContainer" Height="35" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform Y="0"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Rectangle Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="#97000000" Stroke="#00000000" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>

        </Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <VideoPlayer:mediaControl   Height="35" x:Name="mediaControls" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It is play controls for your Video Player

Comment: I tried your code, but can not see the progress bar. Can you see progress bar?

Comment: Add this to your code:
mediaControls.Media = mediaPlayer; 
It will create progressbar. 
Or create new MediaElement  set its Source property to your video
and assign it to MediaControl.Media

Comment: The code is already there. Any ideas to analyze further? Could you post your screen snapshot please? :-(

Comment: Steps I did:
1.Download xap file from your link.
2.Unzip the xap file and use VideoPlayer reference in my SLV APP
3.Create StackPanel with mediaControl and set it to be on top of other elements
4.Assign video file to media source 
5.Results: Progress bar is created for me automatically and play controls located in place i want.

Comment: In the original code of the player, there is code like RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5", what is its function?

Comment: It is a property that gets or sets the center point of any possible render transform declared by RenderTransform.
If you have Expression Blend Studio you can play with this property and see how it affects your object.
For example if you change RenderTransformOrigin and apply Rotation Transform your object pivot will change according that Transform.

Comment: By the way you don't need to set RenderTransformOrigin property in your case here

Answer (score 1):

Browsing the source code, I see Page.xaml with at the bottom a StackPanel.  Swap the MediaElement and the Grid inside it.

Comment: Hi Hans, I tried with your solution for about 1 hour, but failed. I posted my current XAML code and effect I want to achieve, appreciate if you could take a look and let me know how to change my code to achieve my goal? (you can refer to EDIT 1 section)

Comment: I tried to put the following content into the StackPanel, but not displayed.

                <Canvas x:Name="CanvasTest">
                    <TextBlock Text="Test" Canvas.ZIndex="99"></TextBlock> 
                </Canvas>